# Console returning undefined

Tags: meteor

When I write this in console I get undefined however the data is in the database. What am I missing?

```
Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId},{fields: {"profile.pastEmployer.name": 1}});
```

Comment: It sounds like that particular user hasn't been published.

Comment: I can see it using meteortoys:allthings so I assume that means it has been published.

Comment: this.userId refers to the current user doesn't it?

Comment: No, only in pushers and methods. Otherwise you should use `Meteor.userId()`.

Comment: This is doing my head in. I published it just to be sure and now I'm getting object with the userId displaying but not the information I'm asking for

Comment: What happens when you console.log(this.userId)?

Comment: it returns undefined

Comment: Try `Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId() },{fields: {"profile.pastEmployer.name": 1}});`.

Comment: @bp123 If you want the current user's information, you can just use `Meteor.user()` instead of the above mentioned code.

Comment: this is what i get. `Object {profile: Object, _id: "GNMvpRn2YW6QTSSMN"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you may want to do is this:

```js
var pastEmployerName = Meteor.user().profile.pastEmployer.name;
```

Depending on how confident you are in the existence of those nested properties, you may want to use a [guard](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) like so:

```js
var profile = Meteor.user().profile;
var pastEmployerName = profile && profile.pastEmployer && profile.pastEmployer.name;
```

Some things to note:

1. Use `Meteor.userId()` to get the current user's id, and `Meteor.user()` to the the current user's document. In publishers and methods, we use `this.userId`.
2. A fields projection (as used in your original question) gives you an object including an `_id` and the minimal structure to display the specified field(s). In your case, you'd expect to get an object with an `_id` and a `profile`, which in turn contains a `pastEmployer` and so on. In general, fields projections are beneficial on the server (they save on bandwidth and CPU), but are of limited use on the client because the complete documents are already in memory.

Comment: Thanks David. This works. Can you explain why (to help me understand), why do you need to use `profile && profile.pastEmployer && profile.pastEmployer.name;` instead of just `profile.pastEmployer.name`

Comment: See the linked article about guards. In short, it's a way to avoid throwing an error if one of the referenced fields doesn't exist. E.g. if you do `x.y.z` and either `x` or `y` doesn't exist, an error will be thrown. The above technique will safely short circuit in the bad case, and return the correct value in the good case.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the link. I appreciate your explanation and I'll have a read. Thanks heaps for your help!

Comment: No problem. I should also note that if you are confident that all users will always have the required fields, you can just use the first line: `Meteor.user().profile.pastEmployer.name`

Comment: Lol. I'm never confident with this stuff! Thanks again